# Website URL for jqwidgets appears momentarily in the grid after page load

Tags: .net, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I am using `jqxgrid` for displaying tabular data. However whenever the page loads, the website URL http://www.jqwidgets.com momentarily flashes within the grid and fades out after about 5 seconds. I would like to hide that URL from displaying. Is it possible and how can it be achieved. Please refer the sample grid image.

[image: Sample Grid Image]

Below is the code used to display the grid.

```
m("#RequestgridNote").jqxGrid(
                                    {
                                        width: '100%',
                                        pageable: true,
                                        autorowheight: true,
                                        autoheight: true,
                                        enabletooltips: true,
                                        columnsheight: 30,
                                        source: datasourcerequestedNote,
                                        altrows: true,

                                        columns: [
                                            { text: '@Resources.message_properties.denom_Desc', datafield: 'denom_Value', align: 'left', cellsalign: 'right', classes: "grid-col", editable: false, width: '23%', cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer_right },
                                            { text: '@Resources.message_properties.CCType_Code', datafield: 'RcurrTypecd', align: 'left', cellsalign: 'left', classes: "grid-col", editable: false, width: '23%', cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer_left },
                                            { text: '@Resources.message_properties.noofpieces', datafield: 'totalnopiece', align: 'left', cellsalign: 'right', classes: "grid-col", editable: false, width: '23%', cellsrenderer: cellsrenderer_right },
                                            {
                                                text: '@Resources.message_properties.amount', datafield: 'amount', align: 'left', cellsalign: 'right', classes: "grid-col", editable: false, width: '31%', cellsrenderer:
                                                function (index, datafield, value, defaultvalue, column, rowdata) {
                                                    var namount = parseFloat(value);
                                                    return "<div style='margin-top: 10px; margin-right:13px; font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana;' class='jqx-right-align'>" + datasourcerequestedNote.formatNumber(namount, 'f2') + "</div>";
                                                },

                                            },
                                        ],
                                    });
```

Comment: If nothing else you could probably disable it in your page's css.

Comment: Please share us your grid code, are you fetching the data from the JQWidget's server? Please try using some local data if yes.

Comment: Grid code has been added for reference. Data is being fetched from the application database and not from JQWidget server.

Answer (score 0):

Download the jqwidgets.zip from http://www.jqwidgets.com/download/ rather than downloading it from bower or npm! Hard to believe, but the guys from jqwidgets do not share exactly the same files between bower/npm and their download page!